# PHP - filter, keep any keys on multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have a array (return from model):

```
$array = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Name 1',
        'date' => '2016'
        'other' => '...'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Name 2',
        'date' => '2016'
        'other' => '...',
        'children' =>
            [
                'id' => 3,
                'name' => 'Name 3',
                'date' => '2016'
                'other' => '...',
                'children' =>
                    [
                        ....
                    ]
            ]
    ],
];
```

I want to filter this array, just keep keys: `id`, `name` & `children`, like:

```
$array = [
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'Name 1'
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Name 2'
        'children' =>
            [
                'id' => 3,
                'name' => 'Name 3'
                'children' =>
                    [
                        ....
                    ]
            ]
    ],
];
```

I tried to keep important data, remove keys not 'id', 'name' & 'children', then convert this array to json.

Please help me! Thank you!

Comment: yes exactly what are you trying to do .. :p

Comment: I tried to keep important data, then convert this array to json

Comment: Look into [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursive functions are your friends here! 
Something like this:

```
function filter(array $array)
{
    $filteredArray = array();
    $allowedKeys = array('id', 'name', 'children');

    foreach($array as $index => $element)
    {
        $filteredArray[$index] = array();
        foreach ($element as $key => $value) 
        {
            if(is_array($value) && in_array($key, $allowedKeys))
            {
                $filteredArray[$index][$key] = filter($value);
            }
            else
            {
                if(in_array($key, $allowedKeys))
                {
                    $filteredArray[$index][$key] = $value;
                }
            }
        } 
    }
    return $filteredArray;    
}
```

I have not tested it, so maybe you'll need to do some debugging.

Comment: Look into [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) an other array_* functions

Comment: @Michael he needs to filter also the data present in all the keys labelled as "childern", so i don't think that array_map can do the work. Maybe he can do it with array_walk_recursive though.

Comment: This just return params with ids 1 & 2, id 3 was disappeared.

Comment: @AuZu i've edited my code. However you should also check your data structure, as the key "children" should contain an array of children, while in your example it only contains 1 child information.

Comment: @Massimiliano Fedel: Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  function minifyarray($item){
         $newitem = [
              'id' => $item['id'] , 
              'name' => $item['name']
         ];

         if(!empty($item['children']))
             $newitem['children'] = array_map('minifyarray', $item['children']);

         return $newitem;
    }

  $newarray = array_map('minifyarray', $array);
```

Comment: It filtered with ids: 1 & 2, but not with id 3

Comment: how to define and call minifyarray function in Laravel model class?

Comment: I suggest you put this on your controller not on your model

Answer (score -1):

just make loop and unset unwanted stuff

```
function recursivelyRemoveUnwantedStuff($input){
    if(array_key_exists('date',$input)){
          unset($input['date']);
    }

    if(array_key_exists('other',$input)){
          unset($input['other']);
    }

    if(array_key_exists('children',$input)){        
        $input['children'] = recursivelyRemoveUnwantedStuff($input['children']);
    }

    return $input;        
 }
```

and then

```
<?php outPutArray = recursivelyRemoveUnwantedStuff($inputArray); ?>
```

Comment: It has too much keys need remove. I have found the answer from @Massimiliano Fedel